# How to use contextdata in node-nlp properly?

Tags: nlp, chat, chatbot

I am currently trying to create a chatbot and adding some contextdata to it, like in this example: https://github.com/axa-group/nlp.js/tree/master/examples/14-ner-corpus

I have tried several variants of configs, filenames, file paths etc. I even looked up the source code if the contextdata corpus gets read, which it does.

But at the end when running my code against "what is the real name of spiderman?" the {{ hero }} part gets replaced, but the {{ _data[entities.hero.option].realName }} doesn't.

My code currently looks like this:

```
import { NlpManager, ConversationContext } from 'node-nlp'
const manager = new NlpManager({
    languages: ['en'],
    forceNER: true,
    autoSave: false,
    nlu: { useNoneFeature: true }
})
const context = new ConversationContext()
manager.addCorpora('./corpus.json')
await manager.train()

const response = await manager.process(
    'en',
    'what is the real name of spiderman?',
    context
)
console.log(response)
```

The corpus files i use are those linked in the example above:

https://github.com/axa-group/nlp.js/blob/master/examples/14-ner-corpus/corpus.json

https://github.com/axa-group/nlp.js/blob/master/examples/14-ner-corpus/heros.json

I hope someone can give me a pointer at what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the help of https://github.com/jesus-seijas-sp

```
const { NlpManager } = require('node-nlp');

(async () => {
  const activity = {
    conversation: {
      id: 'a1'
    }
  }

  const manager = new NlpManager({
    languages: ['en'],
    forceNER: true,
    autoSave: false,
    nlu: { useNoneFeature: true }
  })
  manager.addCorpora('./corpus.json')
  await manager.train()
  const response = await manager.process({ locale: 'en', utterance: 'what is the real name of spiderman?', activity });
  console.log(response)
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

According with this https://github.com/axa-group/nlp.js/blob/master/docs/v3/nlp-manager.md#context
I created another example. Hope it helps you.

```
const { NlpManager, ConversationContext } = require('node-nlp');
const manager = new NlpManager({ languages: ['en'] });
const context = new ConversationContext();

manager.addDocument('en', 'we got married on %date%', 'married.date');
manager.addDocument('en', 'it was at %time%', 'married.time');
manager.addDocument('en', 'that is all', 'married.done');
manager.addAnswer('en', 'married.date', 'Date {{date}} recorded!');
manager.addAnswer('en', 'married.time', 'Time: {{time}} added!');
manager.addAnswer('en', 'married.done', 'Your marriage happened on Date: {{date}} at Time: {{time}}!');

manager.train()
  .then(result => manager.process('en', 'we got married on 22/02/2022', context))
  .then(result => manager.process('en', 'it was at around 12:10', context))
  .then(result => manager.process('en', 'that is all', context))
  .then(result => console.log(result.answer));
const { NlpManager, ConversationContext } = require('node-nlp');
```

then the result is:
Your marriage happened on Date: 22/02/2022 at Time: 12:10!

Removing the "context" in the manager.process:

```
manager.train()
.then(result => manager.process('en', 'we got married on 22/02/2022'))
.then(result => manager.process('en', 'it was at around 12:10'))
.then(result => manager.process('en', 'that is all'))
.then(result => console.log(result.answer));
```

the result is:
Your marriage happened on Date: {{date}} at Time: {{time}}!